# "RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn " error BertFoeSequenceClassification

Tags: nlp, pytorch, bert-language-model, huggingface-transformers, pre-trained-model

I am trying to build Bert model for Arabic Text classification task using pretrained model from https://github.com/alisafaya/Arabic-BERT
i want to know the exact difference between the two statement:

```
model_name = 'kuisailab/albert-large-arabic' 
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = BertForSequenceClassification .from_pretrained(model_name)
```

I fine-tuned the model by adding the following layers on top of the model:

```
for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False

model.classifier = nn.Sequential(
nn.Dropout(0.5),
nn.ReLU(),
nn.Linear(768,512),
nn.Linear(512,2), 
nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1), 
nn.Softmax(dim=1)
)
model = model.to(device)
```

and used the optimizer:

```
optimizer = AdamW(model.parameters(),
                  lr = 2e-5)
```

finally this is my training loop:

```
model.train()

for idx, row in train_data.iterrows():
    text_parts = preprocess_text(str(row['sentence']))
    label = torch.tensor([row['label']]).long().to(device)

    optimizer.zero_grad()

    overall_output = torch.zeros((1, 2)).float().to(device)
    for part in text_parts:
        if len(part) > 0:
            try:
                input = part.reshape(-1)[:512].reshape(1, -1)
                # print(input.shape)
                overall_output += model(input, labels=label)[1].float().to(device)
            except Exception as e:
                print(str(e))

#     overall_output /= len(text_parts)
    overall_output = F.softmax(overall_output[0], dim=-1)

    if label == 0:
        label = torch.tensor([1.0, 0.0]).float().to(device)
    elif label == 1:
        label = torch.tensor([0.0, 1.0]).float().to(device)

    # print(overall_output, label)

    loss = criterion(overall_output, label)
    total_loss += loss.item()
    
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
```

and i get the error:

```
mat1 dim 1 must match mat2 dim 0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-33-5c2f0fea6c1f> in <module>()
     39     total_loss += loss.item()
     40 
---> 41     loss.backward()
     42     optimizer.step()
     43 

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py in backward(tensors, grad_tensors, retain_graph, create_graph, grad_variables)
    130     Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(
    131         tensors, grad_tensors_, retain_graph, create_graph,
--> 132         allow_unreachable=True)  # allow_unreachable flag
    133 
    134 

RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn
```

any idea how to solve this error

Comment: What is the error that you faced?

Comment: "RuntimeError: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn" after I used Automodel i get this error

Comment: What's your `model_name`?

Comment: 'kuisailab/albert-base-arabic'  a pretrained model for Arabic text

Comment: I also get the same error when i used the larg version of the model: "kuisailab/albert-large-arabic" do you have any idea why is that

Comment: I tried it, and it works perfectly. Sees there is some other mistake.

Comment: Can you please update the question with more details such as lines causing the error and stack trace.

Comment: I edited it, Please recheck

Comment: Here, you don't need to add a layer on top of it. "Sequential models" already contain linear layers on top of the pre-trained model, and also appropriate cross-entropy loss.

Answer (score 1):

`BertForSequenceClassification` is the class which extends the `BertModel`, i.e, `BertForSequenceClassification` defines a logistic regression layer, for the task of classificiation, with cross-entropy loss, to be jointly fine-tuned or trained on the existing Bert Model.

`AutoModel`, is a class provided in the library that allows to automatically identify the model class based on it's name or the model file contents.

Since you already know that you need a model for classification, you can directly use `BertForSequenceClassification`

Comment: So i can use BertForSequenceClassification when my task is classification for any bert model, right?

Comment: To be specific, you are using ALBERT model, hence you need to use `AlbertForSequenceClassification`